# How can I downgrade visual studio 2017 version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I currently have installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise version 15.9.15 (the latest available in Visual Studio Installer). I want to downgrade to version 15.9.11 due to some issues in my project. I have the installer for 15.9.11 but every time I run the installer, Visual Studio Installer is trying to install the 15.9.15 version.

I've tried with different versions but Visual Studio Installer always switches to 15.9.15 regardless. Is there any other way to downgrade? I've searched online but with no luck.

Comment: I have the same question here. It seems that Microsoft allow downgrading, e.g., from **15.9.X** to **15.8.Y** -- but no option to downgrade from **15.9.X** to **15.9.Y** (where only the least significant number is changed). Here, they have only one fixed version for 15.8, one for 15.7, and so on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

Comment: Based on the comment above, could you downgrade even lower to 15.8 and then upgrade to 15.9.11?

Comment: What is stopping you from moving to VS2019?

Comment: @Kit But how? I cannot find any way to upgrade to a specific version of **15.9.X**, where **X** is the minor version which I want. Microsoft seem to only allow upgrading to the currently *latest* 15.9. I would be glad to be mistaken here, but that's how it looks like.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Code freeze before a deadline. I want to stabilize the application at a fixed version of the toolset before shipping it. Some of its parts have been already tested. And upgrading [to another MSVC version, or even to another minor version of the same toolset] is always a risk of breaking *any* part of the code, including those which have been tested, because new compilers might introduce new bugs. It doesn't happen too often, but I don't want to take these risks right now. Of course I will upgrade later. Generally, I like to upgrade. But not before deadlines.

Comment: I get the code freeze aspect and the time not to upgrade; but Visual Studio is an *editor* and not a compiler. If the project/solution/code specify a specific version of .Net/C#/MVC/.Net core the newer version of Visual Studio **does not change** that. As long as it builds under a build machine that has the minimums of the projects, all is good. I routinely have clients that say, "Use VS2017 and don't use VS2019". So I create the projects in VS2017 and the work in VS2019 routinely. At times I go and build in VS2017 to make sure I haven't introduce any C# 7 coding into C#6 allowed inVS2017. HTH

Comment: Which begs the question, what is failing? If this project is built outside visual studio, is **real problem** linked to a particular to a version of MVC or C#? Or is it truly a visual studio issue such as viewing a XAML file in design time and the **editor** freezes, but the code builds *and runs* fine.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Visual Studio is not only an editor. It contains a toolset with a compiler and linker. And Microsoft *do* release updates to the compiler even between minor versions of the same 15.9.X builds. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.9.19 They have changed something in the C++ optimizer (yes, I write in C++, not C#/.NET). And I don't know what could they break elsewhere in the compiler by making this change. So I'd rather not upgrade right now.